# RuntimeError: Failed to lock Pipfile.lock

Tags: python, django, pip

I tried to install mysqlclient using the command `Pipenv install mysqlclient`.
I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!.
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?